# Unable to find sphinx.yml file

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am running rails 2.2.3 with mysql as database scheme &  thinking sphinx installed as plugin.
I am having two problems :

1) I am unable to find file confing/sphinx.yml. I just have a config/development.sphinx.conf
2) I have specified min_infix_len & enable_start property from define_index method of model. I also have checked development.sphinx.conf file & these properties are correctly set there. But I am not getting any infix search results.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the file in your Rails config folder.

The best tutorial I found was http://chris.finne.us/2010/04/09/multi-server-thinking-sphinx/